# Python Email script trouble

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have a script that will be running nightly.  I want it to send me an email when it fails to complete.  I wrote a short test script to learn how to send an email with Python.  In my IDE it runs without error messages but no email.  I'm running from one of our servers (not the email server) which doesn't have any email restrictions.

I tried it in the Python shell so I can read any messages:

[image: screen capture of my shell]

I tried sending to my gmail account and it get this error:

SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'blahblahblah@gmail.com': (550, '5.7.1 Unable to relay')}

Any ideas??

More info:

I modified the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12424439/5731236) to work with our email.

```
def send_email(user, recipient, subject, body):
    import smtplib

    FROM = user
    TO = recipient if type(recipient) is list else [recipient]
    SUBJECT = subject
    TEXT = body

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("workemailserver.com")
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        print 'successfully sent the mail'
    except:
        print "failed to send mail"
```

With this I can send an email to my coworkers, but not myself.  No biggie because I can use a coworkers email as the sender.  Our "email server" relays the messages to office365, so that's why I cant send to my gmail.

My problem is basically solved.  But I was never able to get the "simpler" code on top to work when I had tried sending to coworkers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for abc@gmail.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505914/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-for-abcgmai)

Answer (score -2):

> SMTPRecipientsRefused: (550, '5.7.1 Unable to relay')

This means the server you used can not relay the message to the target recipient. This usually happens when your email server has configuration issues.